# Combining query result and row count with Spring MongoDB aggregation

Tags: java, spring, pagination, aggregation, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to implement a typical pagination use case with Spring Data MongoDB that provides both the page of the query result and the maximum number of available documents. I've got a working solution, however, I'm unsure if this is reasonable or performing or efficient or ...

So, my steps so far

1. Create a MatchOperation with filter criteria
2. Group and count the number of documents found
3. Add the actual information (a simple ID in this example)
4. Unwind the list of IDs
5. Apply `skip` and `limit` to the pipeline

In code:

```
 List<AggregationOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
 ops.add(match(filterCriteria));
 ops.add(Aggregation.group().count().as("total").addToSet("userId").as("userId"));
 ops.add(Aggregation.unwind("userId"));
 ops.add(skip(page*count));
 ops.add(limit(count));
```

I am using `unwind` since I don't know how to pass the `total count` along the pipeline. The resulting LinkedHashMap looks like this (in JSON style)

```
[
  { total: 13, userId: 100 },
  { total: 13, userId: 101 },
  { total: 13, userId: 102 },
  ...
]
```

I'd have prefered something like this without redundancy:

```
{ total: 13, 
  userIds: [ 100,101,102,...]
}
```

Is it possible (and reasonable) to obtain the second form via aggregation? Is aggregation the appropriate method to achieve this, anyway, or are there better ways? 
Does anything speak against the first solution using `unwind` except for the redundancy?